# How can I extract a JSON object from a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I am extracting column values from a csv file (not the whole file). The values are in JSON format as follows:

```
{u'Other': {'Text': 'Telephone', 'start': 45, 'end': 54, u'value': u'contact information'}}
```

I am able to get these values into a list with the following code (json objects = [6] indicates the seventh column in my csv file):

```
import csv

with open('C:\\file\\path\\to\\csv', 'r') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    json_objects = [6]

    for row in reader:

        single_json = list(row[i] for i in json_objects)
        print ', '.join(single_json)
```

How can I extract the columns as JSON's; not as lists?

Comment: Have you tried json.loads in the json library? [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads)

Comment: Yes, tried json.loads and json.dumps. Unfortunately, both do not work.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example csv file?

Comment: Sure, here is a minimum example that you can put in a csv file     2840,test_category_labeling_highlight,84,3635,0,Other,"{u'Other': {'Text': 'Telephone', 'start': 45, 'end': 54, u'value': u'contact information'}}",8,7,FALSE,

Comment: Is that fragment you show the 7th column in the csv file? Do you want the JSON? its just `single_json = row[6]`. Be warned, if the JSON includes the same character used to encode the csv (for instance, one of the json strings has a comma), the csv reader will split it into more columns.

Comment: In the fragment above, "2840" is in the first column, "test_category_labeling_highlight" is in the second column, etc. I would like to get the seventh column "{u'other: ...". Within this seventh column the commas should not be a problem as they are enclosed in "". I should add that I am not particular about the format. So, it does not need to be in JSON. However, I need a way to use the key "start" to get the value "45", for example. If that can be done with a dictionary or otherwise, that would work for me as well. However, JSON is probably the easiest.

Comment: It looks like @tdelaney nailed it: The CSV reader is only going to return the JSON before the first comma.

Comment: If I run the code with the csv row I posted, I am getting back the whole JSON. So, what @tdelaney wrote does not seem to be an issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import json

with open('csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        single_json = row[6]
        single_json = single_json.replace("u'", "'")
        single_json = single_json.replace("'", '"')
        data = json.loads(single_json)
        print json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

Input file named "csv":

```
2840,test_category_labeling_highlight,84,3635,0,Other,"{u'Other': {'Text': 'Telephone', 'start': 45, 'end': 54, u'value': u'contact information'}}",8,7,FALSE
```

Output:

```
{
    "Other": {
        "Text": "Telephone",
        "end": 54,
        "value": "contact information",
        "start": 45
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, there seems to be an issue with `data = json.loads(single_json)`.

Comment: @You_got_it: Post the traceback. The solution works for me with the sample you gave.

Comment: Here it is `C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/bla.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bla.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = json.loads(single_json)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: @You_got_it: Put a print single_json before the json.loads line and paste the output here. You still have a problem somewhere with your JSON input.

Comment: OK, I can see the output now as well. However, the program still crashes.

Comment: @You_got_it: It might be time to use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com). Put in your code, your example input, and your current output and share the link here.

Comment: OK, here it is: http://pastebin.com/DwJ6PDfY I got it working for the most part (only need to get rid of the back slashes).

Comment: @You_got_it: I added some extra print statements. Can you run your version with them and put the output in pastebin?

Comment: Sure, where can I find the print statements? I do not see additional statements in [link](http://pastebin.com/DwJ6PDfY)

Comment: OK, it seems that the json.dumps is actually not necessary per this [link](http://pastebin.com/RCAWAw6E).

Comment: I put in the json.dumps so that it would print the result, like your code. However, if you just need the dict result in data, then json.dumps is not needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. I appreciate your help very much. I do not seem to be able to upvote your answer, but when I am able to do so, I will certainly come back to this question.

Comment: Don't worry about the upvote, l o l. The important thing is that you got things working!

Comment: Thanks again :-) It is for a good cause (research at university).